# Magento 2 How to add a list of Programatocally products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I followed this tutorial http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/ but I did not understand where to put the code exactly

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
try{
$product
->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
->setAttributeSetId(9) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
->setTypeId('simple') //product type 
->setSku('testsku61') //SKU
->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
->setColor(24)
....
->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
$product->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I put it in the app folder, but it does not show anything to the list of products I need help. thank you in advance

Comment: you are using Magento 1 code in Magento 2, so it won't work, check this url for Magento 2 https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

Comment: thks, do I put it under app directly?

Comment: Depends on where you want to rescue products.